# want to change the timestamp into date in cakephp 2.0

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp, cakephp-2.0

```
usng finc condition i am getting following result. I want to change the my timestamp to date format . while using find condition .
for example :-  $emailLogDetail= $this->LogEmail->find('all', array(
           'fields' => array(
            'LogEmail.*',
            //'date("m/d/Y", strtotime(LogEmail.TimeStamp)) as Date',           
            'User.email'
        ),
         'order' => 'LogEmail.id DESC',
        'joins' => $joins
    ));
```

for now i have commented the date conversion code coz it gives error. but is there any way to convert the timestamp into Date while adding Select query

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [LogEmail] => Array
                (
                    [Id] => 12
                    [Status] => sent
                    [UserId] => 42
                    [Subject] => Confirmation!
                    [Body] => hiiiii
                    [TimeStamp] => 1395912288
                    [ActionName] => Register
                )

            [User] => Array
                (
                    [email] => test@gmail.com
                )

        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
"FROM_UNIXTIME(LogEmail.TimeStamp) as date"
```

with formating

```
"FROM_UNIXTIME(LogEmail.TimeStamp, '%m\%d\%y') as date"
```

What you are asking to store that formating style on core.php and use that on whole application. I suggest you not to take that approach... Here it is--

### at core.php

Configure::write('dateFormat',"FROM_UNIXTIME(LogEmail.TimeStamp, '%m\%d\%y') as date");

Now you can read this from anywhere of your application as-

```
$dateFormat = Configure::read('dateFormat');
$emailLogDetail= $this->LogEmail->find('all', array(
           'fields' => array(
            'LogEmail.*',
            $dateFormat,           
            'User.email'
        ),
         'order' => 'LogEmail.id DESC',
        'joins' => $joins
    ));
```

Comment: thans it works for me but i want to add timestamp to be MMMM dd yyyy HH:mm and i want to define it in core like define("DATETIME_FORMAT","M/d/Y H:i:s");
 but how to merge the theDATETIME_FORMAT constant with the code that you have given so that my datetime format will be standard

Comment: @Piya, I really don't understand what format you really want. What you mean here by standard format? Could you please, show me an example with today's date? And the easiest way is to set your table field as datetime as Cakephp Conversion....

Comment: i want to define the dateformat in my core.php and want to use the same in whole code..like you have define the format "%m\%d\%y" FROM_UNIXTIME(LogEmail.TimeStamp, '%m\%d\%y') as date"
i want it to be defined in core file and want to use that evrywhere

forexample 'DATE_FORMAT(published_on,"%d %M %Y") as pub_date'
in core have defined define("DATE_FORMAT","m/d/Y");
it convert the format in m/d/Y format
i want same to be implemented with FROM_UNIXTIME(LogEmail.TimeStamp, '%m\%d\%y') as date

Comment: but this will works only for LogEmail.TimeStamp what if i have another table with timestamp field?

Comment: why are you making things complex? Easiest way to use php `date()` function. Its not a good idea to alter core while there is other way..